# Pass optional request format to redirected controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my **`routes.rb`** I have certain paths as:

**`match \action_root_path\action => redirect('\controller_path')`**

This works well for all sane cases. But say I were to request with a format appended like:

`localhost:3000\action_root_path\action.xml`

`localhost:3000\action_root_path\action.json`

I handle valid/invalid extension requests in the `ApplicationController` 

But if there is a redirect as per the routes, the format is lost and the check is rendered useless and the redirect is successful.

**EDIT:**

Taking a cue form Robins answer I added the following to my routes:

**`match \action_root_path\action(.format) => redirect('\controller_path.%{format}')`**

But to make this work I also need to add a `:defaults => {:format => 'html'}` because of the `.` that has been added to the redirect path.

Is there a way to make the period also optional?
Better still, can I handle this in a shorter or better way?

I tried setting the redirect path as `redirect('\controller_path(.%{format})')` but that takes the braces quite literally.

**Ruby - 1.8.7

Rails - 3.0.2**

Comment: Don't you backslashes. It's a Windows illness.

Answer (score 0):

You can match for `.:format` and ad it again to the redirection path.

```
match '/action_root_path/action(.:format)', to: redirect('/controller_path.%{:format}'), defaults: { format: 'html' }
```

If you only want to match a path for a internal controller, I suggest you to do it like that:

```
get '/action_root_path/action', to: 'ApplicationController#yourAction'
```

Comment: Had to match the format and add it again. Solution 1 FTW!

Comment: Okay. It seemed to work earlier, but has failed not. I get a `URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): /controller.%{:format})`. I am using Ruby 1.8.7 so the syntax would not match.

Comment: Oh, and which Rails version are you using?

Comment: I set `match "/action_root_path/action(.:format)" => redirect('/controller_path(.%{:format})'), :defaults => {:format => 'html' }`

Comment: Maybe there is a different way to route `format` as a variable?